# Access Shape By Name in Header

Tags: vba, ms-word

My first post so sorry for any errors.

I am trying to replace a image in the header of a document. This will be done a few thousand times.

This line of code:

```
Set shp = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers.Shapes(strPic)
```

Causes:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

and

```
Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes("strPic")
```

Causes:

> Run-time error '-2147024809(80070057): The item with the specified name wasn't found.

I have written in multiple ways and cannot get it to assign `shp` I feel like this is a very simple issue of how I am accessing the header or maybe this whole sub is just wrong. The `strPic` line before get the name of the shape fine.

```
Sub imagerepl()

With Selection
         ' \\ If we selected a InlineShape then convert to Shape
        If .Type = wdSelectionInlineShape Then
            .InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
        End If
    End With

strPic = Selection.ShapeRange.Name
Set shp = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers.Shapes(strPic)

'Capture properties of exisitng picture such as location and size
With shp
    t = .Top
    l = .Left
    h = .Height
    w = .Width
End With

ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange(strPic).Delete


Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\tk\Pictures\DFHlogo.png",        msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)
shp.Name = strPic
shp.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
shp.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue


End Sub
```

Comment: This fixed it:      Set shp = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange(strPic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the header image through the `Range.InlineShapes` collection. For example, the following routine would delete the first image in the collection and then add new image to the header.

```
Dim sh As InlineShape

With ThisDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

    ' Get the first (possibly only, for you) image in the header...
    Set sh = .InlineShapes(1)

    ' Delete it...
    sh.Delete

    ' Add a new image to the header...
    Set sh = .InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\path\to\my.jpg")

    ' Set its properties...
    sh.Width = 100
    sh.Height = 100
    ...

End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much this work great. I had started with inline shapes and could not get it to work. even with mine fixed it adds the picture to the body. Not to mention yours is much more efficient not converting the inline shape

Comment: Happy to help. If you found the answer useful, please consider [upvoting and/or accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.